# Adding single line below name in resume template

Tags: header-footer, texshop, resume, cv

I am using the latex template found here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv

Under the name, I would like to add a single line to convey address and other information. Similar to what I have laid out in Microsoft Word in the header section

Please see attached image for the desired layout. How can I accomplish this? I also want to include the full black line spanning the width of the document (excluding margins) to distinguish the section

[image: desired layout]

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.5in,top=0.5in,right=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}


\name{John Smith} % Your name

\address{123 Broadway \\ City, State 12345} % Your address
\address{123 Pleasant Lane \\ City, State 12345} % Your secondary addess (optional)
\address{(000)~$\cdot$~111~$\cdot$~1111 \\ john@smith.com} % Your phone number and email

\begin{document}


\begin{rSection}{\Letter}
\textifsymbol{18} test \Letter
\end{rSection}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you show us a short code, but working code fragment?

Comment: Added code snippet, would also be interested in removing the indent under each new rSection, but the more pressing question is the original post I have

Answer (score 1):

Slight changes should be done in the main file and the class file. I will show you one by one.

First, the main editing document (.tex file)------

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks,urlcolor=[rgb]{0.5,0,0}}
\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\name{John Smith} % Your name

\address{} % Your address
\address{\faMapMarker\, 123 Main Street, New York, NY 0000 \\ \faGlobe\, website.com \\ \faPhone\, 123456789 \\ \faEnvelope\, john@smith.com}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Now, the resume.cls file to be modified only at some places. Search for bullet in the class file, and replace the same by "vert". The code should read `\def \addressSep {$\vert$}` instead of `\def \addressSep {$\bullet$}`. In the class file itself, search for "head of the document" and use the following code. Note that, I have added `\hrule` between the two addresses.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DOCUMENT: Create the head of the document

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document                     % Begin document
  \printname                        % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{     % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
\hrule
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{     % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}

}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The complete class file for your reference-----

```
% resume.cls

% \documentstyle{resume}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved.  This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}       % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{array}                  % required for boldface tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen}

\nofiles                            % .aux files are not needed for resumes
\pagestyle{empty}                   % resumes do not need page numbers

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HEADINGS: Commands for printing name and address

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}}        % \name command can be used to set name
\def \@name {}                      % Set \@name to empty by default

%\def \addressSep {$\diamond$}         % Set default address seperator
\def \addressSep {$\vert$}

% Three address lines can be specified (directly below name)
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set first and second address (optional) % address three added by Abhinav for his use
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
    \def \@addressone {#1}
  }
{
    \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DOCUMENT: Create the head of the document

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document                     % Begin document
  \printname                        % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{     % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
\hrule
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{     % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}

}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SECTIONS: Create section headings

% Used to create large resume section
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1}
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule
  \begin{list}{}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

% Used to format job listing
\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Default Layout: %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %%    Employer (bold)                     Dates (regular)    %%
  %%    Title (emphasis)                Location (emphasis)    %%
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  {\bf #1}                 \hfill                  {    #2}% Stop a space
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{
  \\
  {\em #3}                 \hfill                  {\em #4}% Stop a space
  }\smallskip
  % \cdot used for bullets, items non-indented
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em}
  \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em}
}{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em}
}

\def\namesize{\huge}
\def\nameskip{\medskip}
\def\addressskip{\smallskip}
\def\sectionskip{\bigskip}
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip}
```

The result is this:

[image: Result of the above tweak]

Hope this resolves your query.

Comment: Can you share the full resume.cls file?

Comment: Sure. I have edited the answer for the class file.

Comment: One should never change a class file (copyright/license issues).

Comment: @Johannes_B: Kindly read the notice in the file. Modifications are permitted, and we are not taking commercial advantages. This is just for understanding of anyone who needs it.